# Flexible background for div

Tags: css, themes, border

I need to apply a border for div boxes, which should look the same even all heights are different. I thought, I can do it with SVG fies, but it doesn't look well. The lines are custom styled (not a static line, more hand styled) and should have the same thickness.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve that?

Kind regards
Henning

Comment: Hi @henning and welcome to SO, can you please post your code of what you tried? That will help us answer.

Comment: Hi Josh, this is my css for one line (top one):

section.border1170x775_300_durchgehend {
    background: url(/images/design/rahmen/test/Linie_400x10_schmal_oben.svg) no-repeat white;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: calc(100% - 25px);
}

The file is here [link]https://lcb.web.a-ov.de/images/design/rahmen/test/Linie_400x10_schmal_oben.svg[/link]

The design should be flexible for mobile and desktop versions. The thickness of all lines should be the same, but can vary on different display sizes.

Answer (score -1):

u can use css

```
.col {
    display: table-cell; /* Make elements inside the container behave like table cells */
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp